# MySQL Field Concatenation

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Category INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

Containing data:

```
ID Category Name
1      1    Item 1-1
2      2    Item 2-1
3      1    Item 1-2
4      2    Item 2-2
```

How do I construct a query to return an every possible combination of rows by category, containing a concatenated list of the ID fields in order?

If I use this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.ID, ',', B.ID) FROM foo A CROSS JOIN foo B WHERE A.Category = 1 AND B.Category = 2
```

I get the following result:

```
1,2
1,4
3,2
3,4
```

And I want:

```
1,2
1,4
2,3
3,4
```

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Comment: Updated my answer based upon additional requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question. This is what I was after:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(Z.ID ORDER BY Z.ID)
FROM
  foo A CROSS JOIN foo B
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ID FROM foo) Z
ON
  Z.ID = A.ID OR Z.ID = B.ID
WHERE
  A.Category = 1 AND B.Category = 2
GROUP BY
  A.ID, B.ID
```

This allows me to expand to an arbitrary number of cross joins, eg for combinations of 3 different categories:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(Z.ID ORDER BY Z.ID)
FROM
  foo A CROSS JOIN foo B CROSS JOIN foo C
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ID FROM foo) Z
ON
  Z.ID = A.ID OR Z.ID = B.ID OR Z.ID = C.ID
WHERE
  A.Category = 1 AND B.Category = 2 AND C.Category = 3
GROUP BY
  A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
```

Thanks to all those who answered.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer based upon additional requirement

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(A.ID, B.ID), ',', GREATEST(A.ID, B.ID)) 
  FROM foo A 
 CROSS JOIN foo B 
 WHERE A.Category < B.Category
```

Initial answer

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(A.ID, B.ID), ',', GREATEST(A.ID, B.ID)) 
  FROM foo A 
 CROSS JOIN foo B 
 WHERE A.Category = 1 
   AND B.Category = 2
```

Comment: For this simple case your answer works (thanks). However, is it possible to scale this up to 3 (or more) cross joins across 3 (or more) categories?